# Проверьте ДЗ по лексической сочетаемости и смысловой совместимости

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Укажите случаи нарушения: а) лексической сочетаемости (способности слов сочетаться друг с другом); б) смысловой совместимости. Исправьте предложения.
1. Наступила война.
2. Лекции выполняют огромную роль в жизни студента.
3. За стеклянными витражами магазина были видны первые посетители.
4. На стадионе жители города стали свидетелями большого театрализованного шоу.
5. Личные запросы должны сочетаться с общественными.
Мой вариант:
1. Началась война (а).
2. Лекции выполняют немаловажную роль в жизни студента (б).
3. За витражами магазина были видны первые посетители (а).
4. Жители города стали свидетелями большого театрализованного шоу на стадионе (а).
5. Личные потребности должны сочетаться с общественными (б).
При этом предложения 1 и 5 я исправил верно, остальные - нет (источник - преподаватель). Как сделать правильно?

Comment: На форуме не выполняют д/з. Вы можете представить свой вариант, а мы, если нужно,поможем вам разобраться.

Comment: Что ж... Я представил свой вариант.

Comment: Пишу здесь, в поле  ответа не могу написать.

Comment: а) правильно б) играют роль в) За витринами магазина появились первые покупатели  г) Жители города увидили большое театрализованное представление на стадионе/ На стадионе жители города увидили большое театрализованное представление д) правильно

Comment: Читайте " Нарушения лексической сочетаемости". Научитесь самостоятельно все делать.

Comment: @Серж пожалуйста, используйте комментарии по назначению. Ответы в комментариях будут удаляться.

Comment: @ Aer, когда я отвечал, поле для ответов было недоступным.

Comment: @Серж в таком случае стоит перенести ваши ответы в ответ, а сами комментарии отметить с помощью флажка как устаревшие.

Comment: @Серж если вы хотите, чтобы вашему адресату приходили оповещения, не ставьте пробел после @ и запятую после имени участника.

Comment: @ Aer, думаю, мои комментария можно удалить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, что в итоге у меня получилось.

**1.    Наступила война. -> Началась война (а).**
 Слово «наступила» лексически несовместимо со словом «война». Поэтому используем подходящий синоним этого слова – «началась».

**2.    Лекции выполняют огромную роль в жизни студента. -> Лекции играют огромную роль в жизни студента. (а)**
Слово «выполняют» лексически несовместимо со словом «роль». По-этому используем более подходящее слово – «играют».

**3.    За стеклянными витражами магазина были видны первые посетители. -> За стеклянными витринами магазина были видны первые покупатели. (б)**
Витраж – это произведение изобразительного декоративного искусства или орнаментального характера из цветного стекла, рассчитанное на сквозное освещение. Однако через них мало что можно увидеть, поэтому слово «витражи» следует заменить словом «витрины», которые дают возможность человеку, находящемуся снаружи увидеть товары магазины, а продавцу или иному лицу, находящемуся внутри магазина, увидеть, что происходит снаружи.
Замена слова «посетители» словом «покупатели» не так необходима, как в первом случае. Однако в большинстве случаев люди приходят в магазин с целью что-то купить, так что я решил, что замена целесообразна.
Таким образом, это были нарушения смысловой совместимости.

**4.    На стадионе жители города стали свидетелями большого театрализованного шоу. -> Жители города увидели большое театрализованное шоу на стадионе (б).**
Ошибка заключается в использовании словосочетании «стали свидетелями» и связана с не различением сфер деятельности, так как в сфере театрально-концертной деятельности, о которой идет речь в предложении, используется слово «зритель». Следовательно, это нарушение смысловой совместимости.

**5.    Личные запросы должны сочетаться с общественными. -> Личные потребности должны сочетаться с общественными. (б)**
Слово «запрос» означает «документ, запрашивающий о чем-нибудь». А в данном предложении под «запросами» подразумевается «нужда в чем-либо», то есть следует использовать слово «потребности». Следовательно, это нарушение смысловой совместимости.

Благодарю Серж за оказанную помощь (см. комментарии).

Comment: Вы хорошо справились!